# .NET Find Certificate by thumbprint via AppSetting

Tags: .net, vb.net, certificate, app-config

This one is really weird and I can't figure out why one method works and one doesn't.

I have a certificate in my local computer store and a thumbprint for it.  The app uses the cert when making HTTP web requests so I need to fetch it.  I want to store the thumbprint in the web.config as an AppSetting value.  Whenever I pull the AppSetting value and use it to Find the certificate, it doesn't find it.  However, if I make a local variable (class variable, readonly, const, whatever...) and search by it, it works.  I've done String.Compare() on both the value is **exactly**  the same.  What gives?  I tried to look at the IL to see if I can see something funky but nothing.

```
' This Works '
Dim certificateThumbprint As String = "D0650C9D31CF525D3C82153DCEBC3C3265D75FE3"
Dim certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumbprint, False)

' This doesn't '
Dim appSettingcertificateThumbprint = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CertificateThumbprint")
Dim certCollection2 = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, appSettingcertificateThumbprint, False)

' Intermediate window shows that '
String.Compare(certificateThumbprint, appSettingcertificateThumbprint, True) = 0
```

Comment: Why do you compare strings with `ignoreCase=True`? Try another overload of the `String.Compare(String, String, StringComparision)` and call it with `StringComparision.InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 6):

So it turns out when you copy and paste the thumbprint string from the certificate's properties window, it's possible to also carry over an invisible hex character that won't show up in your Visual Studio window. ([see here](http://petarvucetin.me/blog/2010/05/wcf-invalid-hexadecimal-string-format/))

What I ended up doing was copying the thumbprint to Notepad++, going a line below it, typing it exactly how I saw it, copying it back to the web.config, and running from there. That seemed to work out perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, no dice. It was literally just sucking in a different string from the app.config due to that non-printing character.

Answer (score 4):

I have also found exactly the same issue and after extensive searching, found no answers other than the kind of thing that you have suggested above.

Perhaps Microsoft could comment on their matching methodology for the Certificates.Find function so that we would have a chance of using the built in features reliably.

Answer (score 2):

- Paste into Notepad++
- Switch encoding to ANSI
- Delete garbage characters
- Copy
- Paste into web.config

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
Dim certStore = New X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
Const certificateThumbprint As String = "E846D7787F9D43C136FFEBDD03DEDA8DE83E20D8"
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
Dim certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,certificateThumbprint, False)


' This doesn't ( Now it does :)
Dim appSettingcertificateThumbprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CertificateThumbprint").Substring(2)
Dim certCollection2 = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, appSettingcertificateThumbprint, False)
```

Note the .SubString(2) after extracting from Configuration Manager. you can check why i did that if you do a .ToCharArray() on both the strings and inspecting the array in Watch Window. The one coming from AppSettings had 2 extra characters in the beginning. Your case might be different so i suggest .ToCharArray and editing the string accordingly.

I am not sure why .NET does this though.

Good luck !

Comment: In future, I would suggest copy pasting the string from the certificate manager window to something like Run window or notepad, edit out the string and then copy/paste from Run/Notepad to web.config. I went through the same frustrating experience you have..

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your WORKING version specifically DIMs the variable AS STRING, whereas the non-working version doesn't specify the AS STRING (therefore you're getting an OBJECT).

You should EITHER Dim appSettingcertificateThumbprint AS STRING or use the .ToString method when you USE it (in the .Find method).